# How to store global attributes (per skill) using Alexa SDK DynamoDB persistence adapter

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

The Alexa SDK (ask-sdk) comes with a [persistence adapter](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Managing-Attributes.html#persistenceadapter) that allows to store attributes as key/value pairs in a DynamoDB instance in a semi transparent way. I tried it and it stores attributes per each user, i.e. the primary key of the generated table is the user id. This is useful to store user settings but not useful to store global data, like, e.g. a leaderboard.

How can I use this adapter to store attributes globally at a skill level (not per user id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. The solution is to use change the "key generator function" in the persistence adapter that basically tells the adapter what to use as primary key in the database.

Here's a full demo showing how to do that with Alexa node.js SDK DynamoDB persistence adapter and with the S3 persistence adapter:

https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/70c979f671660fea811ccfb63801f936

In the example above the key generator function is changed to return the skill id instead of the user id so the attributes are then store globally (at a skill level), not at a user level.